# How do I find out what is the hard disk for OS in Linux

Tags: rhel, fdisk, block-device, parted, lsblk

in our bash scripts , we have many places in the code that need to capture only the disk that related to OS ( operation linux/RHEL system )

we are using Linux versions as `7.2/7.5/7.6/7.9` , and on most cases machines have additional disks that used to store data or DB servers that include disks with TB size etc

usually we used the following cli in order to capture the OS disk

```
os_disk=` lsblk -l | grep part | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/[0-9]/ /g' | sort -u | head -1 `
```

It works when no additional parted disks are exists,
but when we have additional disks that are parted as below example:

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdb
sdb                8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdc
sdc                8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdd
sdd                8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sde
sde                8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sde1             8:65   0 931.3G  0 part
└─sde2             8:66   0 931.7G  0 part
sdf                8:80   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdg
sdg                8:96   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdh
sdh                8:112  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdi
sdi                8:128  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdj
sdj                8:144  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdk
sdk                8:160  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdl
sdl                8:176  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdm
sdm                8:192  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdn
sdn                8:208  0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdo
sdo                8:224  0 557.9G  0 disk
├─sdo1             8:225  0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sdo2             8:226  0 557.4G  0 part
  ├─VGPO-lvm_root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VGPO-lvm_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VGPO-lvm_var  253:2    0   100G  0 lvm  /var
```

then we get wrong results that OS disk is `sde` instead to get `sdo`

```
 os_disk=` lsblk -l | grep part | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/[0-9]/ /g' | sort -u | head -1 `
 echo $os_disk
 sde
```

so in that case we need to find other approach that gives the OS disk , when machine could be VM machine or physical machine

Comment: You get the result you asked for. The first line containing part (head -1) is `├─sde1             8:65   0 931.3G  0 part`.

Comment: Try this: `lsblk -l|sed -n "/.*[[:space:]]*\/[[:space:]]*$/p"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the disk containing the partition mounted on a system mount point, *e.g.* `/boot`:

```
lsblk -ls | awk '$NF == "/boot" { m = 1; next } m && $NF == "disk" { print $1 ; exit}'
```

This also works for `/`:

```
lsblk -ls | awk '$NF == "/" { m = 1; next } m && $NF == "disk" { print $1 ; exit}'
```

This uses `lsblk`’s list mode (`-l`) to simplify parsing, and reverses the tree (`-s`) so that the parent disk appears after the partition we’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `findmnt` command?  I've used `findmnt` to get the device for the root filesystem in a script:

```
findmnt -ensP -M /
```

Searches `/etc/fstab` and on my test machine produces:

```
TARGET="/" SOURCE="/dev/nvme0n1p1" FSTYPE="ext4" OPTIONS="rw,discard,errors=remount-ro,x-systemd.growfs"
```

These are the default output fields for the "list" format.  My scripts defined a custom set of output fields, which also sets the order they're printed:

```
findmnt -ensP -o SOURCE,TARGET,FSTYPE,SIZE,UUID,LABEL -M /
```

Produces:

```
SOURCE="/dev/nvme0n1p1" TARGET="/" FSTYPE="ext4" SIZE="39.2G" UUID="1ca031f6-4004-4f8d-a861-532a0158c91f" LABEL=""
```

`findmnt` has many options, among which is `--tree` to produce a tree like your question's `lsblk` output.

The options I use above are:
`-e` - "evaluate" the values in certain fields, converting them to devices.  (without `-e` my SOURCE field would have been `SOURCE="UUID=1ca031f6-4004-4f8d-a861-532a0158c91f"`)
`-n` - no header line in output
`-s` - read /etc/fstab (or `-m` to read /etc/mtab)
`-P` - output in "Pair" format `FIELD="VALUE"` (I found this easier to parse in a shell script)
`-M` - Limit the output to the filesystem mounted on this mount point

There are a number of other options giving a lot of flexibility.  For example, `-t ext4` to limit the search to `ext4` filesystems.

Final note:  `findmnt` finds the info on mounted filesystems (via `/etc/mtab`), or ones listed in `/etc/fstab` (mounted or not).  It can't find ones that aren't mounted and aren't in `/etc/fstab`.  For that you need `lsblk` or possibly the old `blkid`.

Comment: `findmnt --noheadings   --output=SOURCE /`